# No overload for 'addfilestolist' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

Tags: c#, multithreading

i'm trying to start a thread and passe array as a parameter to the method (addfilestolist) which takes arrays as parameter but i have this problem right here :
No overload for 'addfilestolist' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'

here is my code :

```
public void addfilestolist(Array files)
    {

        ListViewItem item;
        FileInfo file_info;
        foreach (string j in files)
        {

            file_info = new FileInfo(j);

            item = new ListViewItem(j);
            item.SubItems.Add(file_info.Extension);
            item.SubItems.Add(file_info.Length.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add("TODO crc");
            item.SubItems.Add(j);

            listView1.Items.Add(item);
            listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        }
    }
```

this is where i created the thread and started it :

```
 using (OpenFileDialog ofg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                ofg.CheckFileExists = true;
                ofg.Multiselect = true;
                ofg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";

                if (ofg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(addfilestolist));
                    t1.Start(ofg.FileNames);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate signature needs to match; the good news is: there are lots of ways to do that via lambdas; for example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(state => addfilestolist((string[])state));
t1.Start(ofg.FileNames);
```

or:

```cs
string[] arr = ofg.FileNames;
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => addfilestolist(arr));
t1.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you Marc Gravelli tried the first one and it seems to be working !!